# TSQL - Search a date in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

suppose that I have a table like this (it's like a history table for all Signatures ):

```
Id  Signature   From          To 
1   S01         2014-01-26    2016-01-26
2   S02         2016-01-26    2016-02-26
3   S03         2016-02-26    2016-04-26
```

Now I want to find out what's the signature in a date like `2015-03-30`?

Comment: where date between from and to

Comment: Really? You had the time to write a question, but not for reading docs? Please read [ask] in [help].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `between`:

```
DECLARE @date date = '2015-03-30'

SELECT [Signature]
FROM YourTable
WHERE @date between [From] and [To]
```

Sample execution with the given sample data:

```
DECLARE @DateTest TABLE (Id INT, [Signature] VARCHAR(5), [From] DATE, [To] DATE);

INSERT INTO @DateTest (Id, [Signature], [From], [To])
VALUES
(1, 'S01', '2014-01-26', '2016-01-26'),
(2, 'S02', '2016-01-26', '2016-02-26'),
(3, 'S03', '2016-02-26', '2016-04-26');

DECLARE @date DATE = '2015-03-30';

SELECT [Signature]
FROM @DateTest
WHERE @date BETWEEN [From] AND [To]
```

Comment: You beat me, so added my work out code in your post.

Comment: Thanks, I just finished with cte to add and here comes your edit

Comment: Oh, please post your `with cte` code and remove mine, no worries

Comment: No offense!! I kindly thank you for your edit! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use:

```
select Signature   
from history
where '2015-03-30' between from and to
```

Answer (score 0):

One Date

```
SELECT signature FROM Table where '2015-03-30' between from and to
```

OR

```
SELECT signature FROM Table where from<='2015-03-30' and to>='2015-03-30'
```